# How to enable vs terminal git command autocomplete when connected to remote ssh?

Tags: git, ssh, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am not able to do autocomplete of my git commands on vs code integrated terminal when connected to remote ssh.

Autocomplete works when I am using terminal externally.

Can some help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first where your bahs completion is activated on your remote server rc file.
Check where you do see (on the remote server account directory):

```
[[ -r "/usr/local/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh" ]] && . "/usr/local/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh"
```

Is it in:

- ~remoteAccount/.bashrc
- ~remoteAccount/.bashrc_profile
- ~remoteAccount/.profile

[`microsoft/vscode-remote-release` issue 83](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/83#issuecomment-542116294) seems to indicate only `.bashrc` is sourced.

In your case, once the remote SSH session is opened in VSCode, try and source manually the file where the `bash_completion.sh` is declared.

Comment: Nn my remote server, I tried to locate the file but didn't have any luck. 
Also `/usr/local/etc` folder seems to be empty.

Comment: @SiddhantNaik Maybe git is not installed on the remote server, which means there is no bash completion (like described in https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/wiki/Install-Bash-git-completion) to activate.

Comment: I found the bash_completion file and also git is installed. 
But to modify this file I will require root access which I don't have. So I will contact the admin to do this.

Thanks for the help. Cheers..